# how to represent a many to many relationship with many records with a HTML based user interface

Tags: php, html, django, user-interface, many-to-many

I am using django, but this can apply to any html based web technology.

I want to allow a user to associate many records with a record entry.

With a few records this could be done like this:

[image]

The problem is when organizations are in the thousands and you can't scroll through them.

Are there any best practices or optimal ways make these type of many to many associations in html based user interfaces?

Comment: My first thought is pagination. My second thought is filtering based on what the user has typed in.

Comment: Can the many items (organizations) be grouped or structured in some way? For instance, alphabetically?

Comment: If there are 1,000s of items then who is going to look at those entries let alone select them an place them in a list. I would re-think the interface and maybe placing the organisations into categories (which should produce smaller lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple user interfaces that can be used in order to increase the usability of your application.

**1. Typeahead**

This is used widely by Twitter, Facebook and instagram in order to let the user search through the data. Also can be used for multiple selection.

https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

**2. Search in a Dropdown**

This allow the user to click on the dropdown then filter then select multiple items as he/she like.

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

**3. Tags input**

Used a lot with tags selections which are always multiple and wide.

http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

For me I prefer a typeahead that will add the selected item to a placeholder and show it to the user with a times icon in order to delete. You may want to use `AJAX` to get the typeahead data instead of passing 1000 records to the page in one time.

Hope this helps.